# in R: Using loop to let one column equal a list of names dependent on a list of names in another column in R

Tags: r, loops, replace, apply, factors

I am new to loops - actually, I don't understand them, and generally try to find simpler alternatives. Here I have a simple dataset:

```
spp = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "D","D")
Genus = as.vector(rep(1,6))
df = data.frame(cbind(spp,Genus), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

I want to replace whatever is in column "Genus" with a particular genus name, based on the contents of column "spp". This is what I have done:

```
df$Genus[(df$spp == "A")] = "Apple"
df$Genus[(df$spp == "B")] = "Bla"
df$Genus[(df$spp == "C")] = "Cat"
df$Genus[(df$spp == "D")] = "Donkey"
```

While it returns the needed result, I am looking for a way that I can loop this function without having to repeat myself? My attempts have involved trying to use `levels(df$spp)` in various `if` and `for` and `apply` functions, but all have failed dismally and returned errors that I don't understand. All the basic examples of looping I looked at only use very simple functions, but I don't know how to apply a loop to a slightly more complex function with two parts, as above? Any advice will be much appreciated!

Francois

Comment: Use a lookup table with a named vector. Here is a working example. `lookup <- c("A"="Apple", "B"="Bla", "C"="Cat", "D"="Donkey"); 
df$Genus <- lookup[match(df$spp, names(lookup))]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try a `switch()` statement with `lapply`.

```
df$Genus <- lapply(df$spp, switch, "A"="Apple", "B"="Bla", "C"="Cat", "D"="Donkey")

df
# spp  Genus
#   A  Apple
#   B    Bla
#   C    Cat
#   A  Apple
#   D Donkey
#   D Donkey
```

The `lapply` will operate in a recursive manner assessing the value of `spp` and switching the value out with the associated value from the expression and assigning it to the `Genus` column.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dan, that was very simple and effective